# How to integrate ParametricNDSolve solution and solve for parameter based on integration result

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I have a second-order ODE that depends on a parameter $\rho_0$. For a given $\rho_0$, I can use NDSolve or ParametricNDSolve to get the solution $y(r; \rho_0)$ very easily, but I want to solve for the value of $\rho_0$ that satisfies the following (admittedly complicated) condition:
$$4\pi\rho_0\int_0^Rr^2 e^{-y(r; \rho_0)} dr = M $$
where M and R are given.

I've tried doing this several different ways, using different combinations of (Parametric)NDSolve(Value), NSolve, and FindRoot, and trying solutions from several related posts on here, but I just can't get it to work. Here's one such trial:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
{y''[x] + 2/x * y'[x] == (chi[rho0] * y'[x]^2 + 1)/(chi[rho0] + Exp[y[x]]), 
 y[ibc] == 0, y'[ibc] == 0}, y, {x, ibc, obc}, {rho0}]


FindRoot[(4 Pi * rho0 * 
         NIntegrate[ r^2 * Exp[ -sol[rho][r/r0[rho]] /. rho -> rho0 ], {r, 0, R} ] 
         - M), {rho0, rho0guess}]
```

where rho0guess, chi, and r0 are all defined in advance. When I run this, I get the following error message

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand E^-ParametricFunction[1,Internal`Bag[<1>],0,1,{<<1>>},{NDSolve`base$189416,NDSolve`NDSolveParametricFunction[0,<<8>>,All]}][rho0][<<1>>/Sqrt[<<1>>]] r^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,95.908}}.
```

I think the problem is that NIntegrate is trying to evaluate the solution before a value for rho0 is passed to the solution by FindRoot, and so it's failing to integrate because rho0 doesn't have a numerical value yet. I just can't figure out how to get around this.

Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE: The odd thing is, I can plot the integrated NDSolve solution as a function of the parameter and find the root "by eye" just fine. This process is slow and annoying, but works

```
LogLogPlot[
   4 Pi*rho0*
   NIntegrate[ r^2*Exp[-sol[rho][r/r0[rho]] /. rho -> (rho0)], 
              {r, 0, R} ] / M, {rho0, 10^5, 10^10}]
```

EDIT: Here are some typical values of the various parameters and functions

````
GAU = 4.3*10^-6;
rhobAU = 135.3;

M = 10^11;
R = (M/(4 Pi/3*200*rhobAU))^(1/3);

R0 = 4;
kTm = GAU*M/R/2;
r0[rho0_] := Sqrt[kTm/(4 Pi*GAU*rho0)]
chi[rho0_] := R0^2/(Pi^2*r0[rho0]^2)

rho0guess = 10^8;
```
````

Comment: Can you give typical values for $M$ and $R$? Also, `chi[rho]` is undefined.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, I added them to my post

Comment: @skewlkid521 you can define a new function `y1[x]` with derivative `y1'[x] == x^2 Exp[- y[x]]` and initial condition `y1[0] == 0` and add it to your system of differential equations. It can then be used in `FindRoot` without any issues. I can't test your system `ibc`, `obc`, but I use that approach in my problems.